# How to display MySQL row when customer enters value from corresponding column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I'm currently working on a wordpress website.

I'm looking to be able to have a customer enter the primarykey of their order, and in return, the status of their order will be displayed.

In other words, I want to be able to display the value of a column when the customer enters the primary key for that row the column is in.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Personally, I think that customers should know nothing at all about the Primary Key of a given table.

Comment: Rubbish, it's just an order number: they can't do much harm with an integer as long as you limit the front end to only display orders that that user has placed.

Comment: If your Primary Key = OrderNumber then does not matter, if Primary Key is not OrderNumber they should not even be aware of that

Comment: The primary key in this case is actually a claim number that only the person submitting the order should know. The customer is the one who sends us their unique claim number and then it is added to the database along with their order status. By having access to this claim number, it's assumed that the customer is qualified to know information surrounding said number. I'm not a database technician but rather general IT so I'm struggling a little bit with finding a solution to this problem.